# JavaScript get position of option element?

Tags: javascript, html, position, html-select

I have a web app that needs to know the position (x/y not index!) of an option element inside a multi select list. It works great in Firefox but no dice in Chrome or IE.

Is it possible to get an option's position in Chrome/IE with JavaScript?

Here is my fiddle displaying the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/jamiller619/Kbh4g/3/ Works with Firefox but not in IE/Chrome.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @j08691 Because I'm letting a user add options to an already defined select list. I thought it would be nice to append a textbox above the new option element so they can enter a new value. My select list can easily be changed to a UL but may be a bit more work than using a SELECT multiple=multiple

Comment: Hmmm position is always 0 for me too, very strange! You could do what you wanted to in your comment without the use of the position which will probably be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - you can't (webkit issue).

But you can cheat!!!

HTML:

```
<div style="position:relative">
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option>Test 1</option>
    <option>Test 2</option>
    <option>Test 3</option>
    <option>Test 4</option>
    <option>Test 5</option>
    <option>Test 6</option>
    <option>Test 7</option>
    <option>Test 8</option>
    <option>Test 9</option>
    <option>Test 10</option>
</select>
</div>
<br />
option position:<br />
Left: <span id="pos-x"></span><br />
Top: <span id="pos-y"></span>
```

CSS:

```
select
{
    font-size:20px;    
}​
```

JQuery:

```
$(function()
{    
    $('select').change(function() {
        var optionHeight = 20; // or get this value from the stylesheet or inline-style
        var textIndent = 1; // best guess or work it out using coordinate crosshair tool
        $('#pos-y').text((this.selectedIndex + 1) * optionHeight);
        $('#pos-x').text(this.offsetLeft + textIndent);
    });
});
```

It's a quick and dirty solution!

UPDATE

CSS:

```
select
{
    height: 150px;
    font-size: 20px;        
}
```

​
JQuery:

```
$(function()
{    
    $('select').change(function() {
        var fontSize = 20; // or get this value from the stylesheet or inline-style
        var lineHeight = fontSize + 4 // need a better calculation here
        var optionHeight = lineHeight;
        var textIndent = 1; // best guess or work it out using coordinate crosshair tool
        var top = (this.selectedIndex * optionHeight) - this.scrollTop; 
        $('#pos-y').text(top);
        $('#pos-x').text(this.offsetLeft + textIndent);
    });
});
```

Comment: Font size is not equal to height in most cases! Also, what about border width, padding and margins? You could make it work this way, but it'll take a lot more.

Comment: With your code `pos-y` will be wrong, if select list will be scrolled.

Comment: @TomSchoffelen option elements are not supposed to have borders, padding or margins and won't work in chrome anyway - plus line-height is not that difficult to work out

Comment: @user1113426 Thanks for pointing out that bug - corrected on post!

Comment: You may also want to `top += this.offSetTop;`

Comment: While this information is certainly useful to know, and does answer my question, I ended up replacing the SELECTS with ULs and custom events.