# option element's jQuery position always 0,0 in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

For a select element:

```
<select id="s1" size="4">
    <option>o1</option>
    <option>o1</option>
    <option>o1</option>
    <option>o1</option>
  </select>
```

The following code always returns 0 0 in IE 11 but 26 9 in Chrome:

```
  var selectelem = document.getElementById("s1");
  var children = selectelem.querySelectorAll("option");
  console.log($(children[1]).position().top + " " + $(children[1]).position().left);
```

Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: Tried using console.log(children[1].getBoundingClientRect()); got same results

Comment: Does not even show up in the IE developper tools (0, 0, auto, auto). A man could use a list instead or calculate the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is still not possible in Explorer. The bounds do not even show up in the developper tool:

[image]

Here is an older question asking for the same:

[JavaScript get position of option element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948885/javascript-get-position-of-option-element)

Alternativly just use a good old list (ul and li):

```
<ul>
    <li>o1</li>
    <li>o1</li>
    <li>o1</li>
    <li>o1</li>
</ul>
```

You could aswell try to calculate the postition, yet it is hardly worth the effort:

```
<html>
    <script>
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            var tS = document.querySelector('select');
            var tB = tS.getBoundingClientRect();

            for(var tL=tS.querySelectorAll('option'), tM=Math.max(tL.length, ~~tS.getAttribute('size')), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; ++i){
                console.log(tB.height / tM * i + tB.top)
                console.log(tL[i], tL[i].offsetTop, tL[i].getBoundingClientRect().top)
            }
        }, 1000)
    </script>

    <body>
        <select id="s1" size="4">
            <option>o1</option>
            <option>o1</option>
            <option>o1</option>
            <option>o1</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```